# Create a Launcher shortcut for Terminator

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, .desktop, terminator

I installed Terminator for Ubuntu 16.04 and when I started it first, I clicked on the *Lock to Launcher* option and moved the icon up the Launcher.

The problem is whenever I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, a new Terminator icon appears on the Launcher, creating two sets of Terminator icons.

I want to keep all the instances of Terminator to be grouped together by a single icon, like File Explorer or Firefox. How can I create a proper shortcut which does that?

Comment: Inspect the `.desktop` files of the other applications in `/usr/share/applications/` . Read the `.desktop` specification at https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/. Read https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en "Desktop files: putting your application in the desktop menus"

Answer (score 3):

I don't actually know why this happen, a simple solution is creating a new shortcut for openning terminator, whatever you like on Settings-->Devices-->Keyboard

[image]