# Terminator icon not showing properly on ubuntu 22.04 dock

Tags: terminator

When I open the terminator console in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS following shows:[image: A gear instead of the actual terminator icon]

This wasn't an issue in Ubuntu 20.04 and I've only seen it happen with the terminator console. I've purged it and reinstalled but the issue remains. What else could I try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is for programming. This question needs to be asked on "Ask Ubuntu".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. Seems to be an [older Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/+bug/1726889).

Simple workaround as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949787/create-a-launcher-shortcut-for-terminator) would be to set your own custom keyboard shortcut for in my case Ctrl + Alt + T.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 as well, and there is the following simple way to fix this:
Open Settings, => keyboard => Keyboard Shortcuts => Custom ShortCuts, and click '+' to add your new custom shortcut. Here, when the dialog appears it will include 3 sections, name, Command, and Shortcut. For example in my case, Name - "Launch Terminator", Command - "terminator", Shortcut - "Ctrl + Alt + T".
After that, you should also disable the original shortcut of the default terminal, "Ctrl + Alt + T" as well.

Answer (score 0):

in the desktop entry of terminator i changed the icon path to absolute, and it worked as well for some time, than after like 2 weeks, the icon broke again. I thought an update reversed my change but it is still showing absolute path. Strange :S